# Detect Virtual Beacon Devices

Tags: uuid, beacon

We have developed an electronic device.

When the beacon is close to our device we check the uuid and if it is correct we run the device.

But we have a problem here.

We just want only our beacons to work with our device.

Someone can copy uuid by listening to the beacon signal. And he can make broadcast uuid with virtual beacon application on mobile phones.

The problem is solved if we write the beacon's mac address to our device's memory on during production. But we can not do this because the user can buy beacon at any time. And our device does not know the mac address of the new beacon.

(User can change UUID, Major and Minor id on mobile beacon transmitter app.)

How do we know if the incoming signal is from our beacon device or from a virtual application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Think of a standard BLE Beacon like a road sign.  It is useful for providing directions to those who see it, but there is no built-in security mechanism to prevent others from copying the same road sign and putting it up somewhere else.  For most use cases, people are content to accept the fact that others won't bother to do this.

For use cases where you must know for sure that the signal is yours, the only sure-fire strategy is to **use an encrypted or hashed beacon signal** that only you have the keys to decode.  Two popular beacon formats support this:  [Eddystone-EID](https://developers.google.com/beacons/eddystone-eid) is sponsored by Google with an open format.  And [Gimbal](https://gimbal.com/beacons/) uses a proprietary system.

Before you use one of these systems, be sure you understand the disadvantages:

1. The systems are somewhat brittle.  If mobile devices cannot reach servers to decode the transmission, or if the clock used to generate / validate the hash is off significantly, the detections will fail.
2. Your beacons must be registered with a third party (Google or Gimbal), so they know everything about them, and you are dependent on their support for your system continuing to work.  Google may not be likely to go out of business soon, but its long-term commitment to supporting Eddystone-EID is questionable.
3. It is much more complex to set up your beacons with systems like these.  Be sure you budget for the extra man hours needed if your project uses them.